# Can we "slightly" change the measure of a set?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Can there be a pair of models $M\subset N$ of ZFC and an $X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})^M$ such that $$0<\mu^*(X)^N<\mu^*(X)^M?$$

*(Here "$\mu^*$" denotes Lebesgue outer measure.)*

That is, can we change the (outer) measure of a set of reals by passing to a larger model *without* killing it completely *(= making it null)*? Certainly we have to have the set $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\mathbb{R}^M$ be "large" in order to do this (for example, $N$ has to contain a real coding a cover of $X$ more efficient than any cover in $M$), but beyond that I can't seem to get any purchase.

I recall seeing a fairly easy proof that the answer is **no**, but I can't reconstruct it or find a reference for it at the moment *(even under additional assumptions - e.g. that $N$ is a generic extension of $M$)*.

Comment: There's an easy proof that the answer is no if you use the Lebesgue measure, measurable sets and $N$ is a generic extension [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88582/can-we-change-the-lebesgue-measure-by-forcing), but I suppose you already know that (things are not as easy with the outer measure, since sets of outer measure $1$ should still have outer measure $1$ in a random forcing extension iirc)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: I was going to link to that! :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I must admit that not seeing either an answer or a comment written by you 37 seconds after the question was posted was rather surprising

Comment: @Alessandro: Yes, on occasion I'm not on the site. It's unfortunate, but it offers others the chance to participate, which is great.

Comment: Let $\textsf{Random}_{\kappa}$ denote the forcing for adding $\kappa$ random reals in $[0, 1]$. Force with $\textsf{Random}_{\omega_1} \star \textsf{Cohen} \star \textsf{Random}_{\omega_1}$ and let the generics be $X = \langle x_i : i < \omega_1\rangle$, $c$ and $Z = \langle z_i : i < \omega_1 \rangle$. Put $Y = Z  + 1 \subseteq [1, 2]$, $M = V[X][Y]$ and $N = V[X][c][Y]$. Then $M \models \mu^{\star}(X \cup Y) = 2$ and  $N \models \mu^{\star}(X \cup Y) = \mu^{\star}(Y) = 1$.

Comment: @hot_queen I think that works - you should add it as an answer! (Incidentally, it also suggests a natural strengthening of the question: suppose $X$ changes measure between $M$ and $N$. Must we be able to partition $X$ into $A,B$ with $A,B\in M$ such that the measure of $A$ doesn't change between $M$ and $N$ and the measure of $B$ is zero in $N$?)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Note that argument doesn't actually need the extension to be a forcing extension: all that's needed is that if $x\in\mathbb{R}^N\setminus\mathbb{R}^M$, then the "wrapped translates" of $[0,1]^M$ by natural number powers of $x$ are disjoint, which follows from the absoluteness of algebraicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*The following answer is due to hot_queen in the comments above; I'm posting it here and accepting it in order to move this question off the "unanswered" queue. If hot_queen posts their argument as an answer I'll upvote/accept it and delete this one; meanwhile, I've marked this CW so I don't get reputation for their work.*

The answer is **yes**. Briefly, we build a model $M$ with a set of reals $X$ in $M$ such that $(i)$ in $M$, both $X\cap [0,1]$ and $X\cap (1,2]$ have positive outer measure but $(ii)$ we can make the former null without making the latter null.

In a bit more detail:

> Over a ground model $S$, add $\omega_1$-many random reals $A=(a_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_1}$ in $[0,1]$, then a Cohen real $c$, then $\omega_1$-many random reals $B=(b_\eta)_{\eta<\omega_1}$ in $(1,2]$. Let $N$ be the whole generic extension $S[A][c][B]$, and $M$ the submodel $S[A][B]$. Then going from $M$ to $N$, $c$ nullifies $A$ but not $B$.

And that basic recipe is highly tweakable.

Of coures this raises the question of whether a mild measure change can happen "irreducibly," which I've asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3491372/another-question-on-changing-measure).