# Another question on changing measure

Tags: logic, set-theory

*Now [asked and bountied](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350093/gently-changing-measure) at Mathoverflow.*

---

This question is a follow-up to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488588/can-we-slightly-change-the-measure-of-a-set), to which hot_queen gave an excellent answer. Briefly, the original question is whether the (outer Lebesgue) measure of a set of reals can change *without becoming zero* when we pass from one model to a larger one. Hot_queen observed that we can achieve this by killing half of the starting set if it is built appropriately (that is, out of two pieces such that we can make one null while keeping the other non-null).

In some sense, though, this isn't totally satisfying. So the following seems a natural follow-up question:

> Can we have a pair of transitive models $M\subseteq N$ of ZFC with some $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})^M$ such that **there are no** sets $B,C\in M$ with
>
> - $A=B\cup C$,
> - $\mu^*(B)^N=0$, and
> - $\mu^*(C)^N=\mu^*(C)^M$?

A good first step towards a negative answer would be ruling out the following extreme situation: a pair of transitive models $M\subseteq N$ where $(i)$ the outer measure of some set of reals in $M$ changes when we go to $N$ but $(ii)$ **every** non-$M$-null set is non-$N$-null. **That's so ridiculous it has to be impossible** ... right?

Meanwhile, on the positive side I'd be excited (if not fully satisfied) by a pair of models of a subtheory of ZFC (although I'd rather not go below ZF).

---

Incidentally, it's known that even the original situation can't happen for $A$ measurable; see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/88583/8133) *(it's stated there for forcing extensions specifically but that's not actually used)*.

Comment: I guess $A$ is not in $\Bbb R^M$ but rather in $\mathcal P(\Bbb R)^M$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Whoops, fixed!